# Indexing file last modified time (on disk) with Solr bin/post tool

Tags: solr

Is there an option to the bin/post tool or some parameter to add to the core xml schema that would allow to add the filesystem file last modified date to the Solr index?

Answer (score 0):

The last modified time for a core is already tracked automatically and is displayed in the Admin UI's core admin screen. You can also retrieve it with the API call: http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?wt=xml